# Uploading to Blobstore without using blobstore.create_upload_url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

I would like to create an app using python on google app engine to handle file upload and store them into the blobstore.

However, currently blobstore requires the use of blobstore.create_upload_url to create the url for the file upload form post. Since I am uploading from another server, my question is, is it possible to upload file to gae blobstore without using that dynamic url from blobstore.create_upload_url?

FYI, it is ok that I request a upload URL from the python script before I upload from another server but this creates extra latency and that is not what I want. Also I read that using the so called "file-like API" from http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore but the documentation didn't seem to cover the part on uploading.

Also, previously I tried to use datastore for file upload, but the max file size is 1MB which is not enough for my case. Please kindly advise, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are exactly two ways to write files to the blobstore: 1) using `create_upload_url`, and posting a form with a file attachment to it, 2) writing to the blobstore directly using an API (with a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638894/how-to-write-big-files-into-blobstore-using-experimental-api) for large files).

If you want a remote server to be able to upload, you have the same two choices:

1) The remote server firsts requests a URL. You have a handler that's just is only to return such a URL. With this URL, the remote server crafts a properly-encoded POST message and posts it to the URL.

2) You send the file data as an HTTP parameter to a handler to your app engine server, which uses the blobstore write API to then write the file directly. Request size is [limited](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits) to 32MB, so the maximum file size you can write using this method will be slightly under that.

Comment: However if I use approach 2, what will be the size limit of the upload?

Comment: Updated with limit for approach #2.